# Trouble using Apache's mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My webroot contains the following:

- `assets/`
- `.htaccess`
- `handler.php`
- `index.html`
- `main.js`
- `style.css`

I make an AJAX request in my `main.js`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/example.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and my `.htaccess` looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ handler.php?test=$1 [L]
```

and yet everytime I do that AJAX request, I get a 404 error in my console, and the request in the network tab shows up red.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What happens if you use `/handler.php...` (with `/`) in your RewriteRule?

Comment: @DusanBajic yep that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Dusan Bajic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145196/dusan-bajic)! The solution to my problem was simply changing

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ handler.php?test=$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /handler.php?test=$1 [L]
```